# Interpolate complex numbers in geometrical sense

Tags: complex-numbers, interpolation

Complex numbers can be used to represent rotations. Is it possible to interpolate between 2 normalized complex numbers in geometrical sense without going through the angles they represent?

Example:

```
a0 => z0 = sin(a0) + cos(a0) * i

a1 => z1 = sin(a1) + cos(a1) * i
```

I would like to obtain:

```
z = ...
```

where `z` represent the angle defined as `a0 + (a1 - a0) * t`, where `t` is `[0, 1]` without actually computing `a0` and `a1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literally, mostly yes. 
In practice, no.

Here's the literal approach: 
Compute 
$$
z = (1-s) z_0 + s z_1
$$
for some $s \in [0, 1]$. Then compute
$$
z' = \frac{z}{|z|}
$$
As long as $a_0$ and $a_1$ differ by less than 180 degrees, as $s$ varies from $0$ to $1$, the number $z'$ will range over all "rotations" between $z_0$ and $z_1$.

Here's the practical part:

The problem is that it won't do so "nicely": if $z_0$ and $z_1$ are near opposites, it'll mostly give you rotations near $z_0$ and $z_1$, "racing through" the rotations in the middle when $s \approx 0.5$.

The exact relation between $s$ and the $t$ you've named can be written out, so it's possible to do select the "s" values carefully to get a uniform-speed variation between $z_0$ and $z_1$...but it involves more mess than computing the angles in the first place.

There's another sense in which it's practically impossible. Consider the case where $a_0 = 0$ and $a_1 = 2\pi$. Then $z_0$ and $z_1$ are identical, and there's no way to know that they didn't arise from $a_0 = 0$ and $a_1 = 0$. If they arose from the first pair, then for $t = 0.5$, you want to compute $z = -1 + 0i$; if they arose from the second, then for $t = 0.5$, you want to compute $z = 1 + 0i$. In short you need to get two different answers from your interpolater *given the same inputs*. That's not possible.

Comment: `z = z0 * (z1 / z0)^t` gives me exactly what I was looking for, uniformly distributed points on the arc between `z0` and `z1`. I'm not sure at the moment how costly is to compute the power of a complex number. This might be worse than computing the angles, interpolating on them and computing again the complex number...

Comment: 1. Yes, it costs just as much, if not more, than computing interpolated angles. 2. It doesn't solve the "difference in angles is $2\pi$" problem. Maybe that never comes up in your case. You might also want to check the case of 0 degrees and, say, 270 degrees. If you're hoping that the interpolated points will pass through, say, 90 degrees, you're going to be disappointed.